# Import a system function (windows - ntsystem.dll)  for use in inline assembly

Tags: delphi

I need to run this code :

```
asm
 push eax
 mov eax, esp
 push 0
 push 4
 ...
 call NtQueryInformationThread
 ...
end;
```

But I get the error message that NtQueryInformationThread is 
"Undeclared identifier: 'NtQueryInformationThread'".

Can you please help me declare it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look into the [`JclWin32.pas`](http://jcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jcl/trunk/jcl/source/windows/JclWin32.pas?revision=3776&view=markup). There you'll find the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are missing is that you need to make your program import the function from `ntdll.dll`. What's more you don't need `asm` for this and you really should avoid using it because it will make your program hard to maintain.

You can import the function just like any other Windows API function:

```
function NtQueryInformationThread(
    ThreadHandle: THandle;
    ThreadInformationClass: THREADINFOCLASS;
    ThreadInformation: Pointer;
    ThreadInformationLength: ULONG;
    ReturnLength: PULONG
): NTSTATUS; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll';
```

You will need a couple of type declarations too:

```
type
  NTSTATUS = LONG;
  THREADINFOCLASS = DWORD;
```