# I need the prototype for calling RtlQueryProcessHeapInformation

Tags: delphi, winapi, function-prototypes

I need to call RtlQueryProcessHeapInformation in Delphi. 
RtlQueryProcessHeapInformation is a function exported from ntdll.dll. 
I don't have a prototype for this function. I get "Undeclared identifier" error.

```
asm 
 ...
 xchg ebx, eax
 pop ebp
 call RtlQueryProcessHeapInformation
 dec ebp
 ...
end;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What makes you think that you need asm for this? You didn't for your last question. What makes you think you need to call this particular private undocumented function? I can't find a prototype for it through websearch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit of websearch leads to [this page](http://read.pudn.com/downloads50/sourcecode/hack/trojan/170997/win32toolkit/ntdll.h__.htm) or [this one](http://read.pudn.com/downloads3/sourcecode/windows/248345/win2k/private/ntos/dll/query.c__.htm) which indicate that the function looks like this:

```
NTSTATUS NTAPI RtlQueryProcessHeapInformation( 
    IN OUT PRTL_DEBUG_INFORMATION Buffer 
);
```

You already know what `NTSTATUS` from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138048/import-a-system-function-windows-ntsystem-dll-for-use-in-inline-assembly). As for `NTAPI`, that's `__stdcall`. So that means the function declaration in Delphi is:

```
function RtlQueryProcessHeapInformation(
    Buffer: PRTL_DEBUG_INFORMATION
): NTSTATUS; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll';
```

The page I link to also includes a declaration for `PRTL_DEBUG_INFORMATION` and I'm sure you can translate that yourself. You'll still have to reverse engineer what the parameters mean since this is an implementation private, undocumented function.

---

This is the second question that you have asked that has been almost identical. In both questions you present the question as being an assembler question. But it's not. In both questions you needed to work out the declaration of the function, and how to import it from the external DLL. What you should take away from this is that when you need to call a function in another DLL you can do one of two things:

1. Import it implicitly with the `external` code that I have shown in both your questions. This is the simpler approach.
2. Use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to explicitly import it. This is the more laborious approach.

Please don't take this the wrong way – I'm just trying to show you what you need to know to be able to solve such problems for yourself.

Comment: David first of all thank you very much for your quick reply. I don't take it the wrong way :)
I really appreciate you proposing solutions. 
In this particular case I could use `LoadLibrary` or `GetProcAddress`. 

I found some code in asm though and I wanted to try it as it is. What's more important is that the `PRTL_DEBUG_INFORMATION` is undocumented and I found it hard to implement your solution from my first question. I still do.

Comment: The links I gave you contain definitions of the struct. But how are you going to work out how to call this API? There's no documentation. My answer answers your question. It doesn't really solve your fundamental problem because you didn't tell us that. What is your overall goal here.

Comment: I'm taking a slight detour from the normal way of doing things just for the fun of learning things.